# Remove double quotes from javascript string

Tags: javascript

```
var tabData='[{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]},{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]}]';
```

I want to remove double quotes from only new Date(" ") wherever new Date (" ") appears.
like- new Date(2017-02-25) ..

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe your *actual* problem and not this misguided attempt at a solution.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var tabData='[{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]},{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]}]';

var output = tabData.replace(/new Date\("([^"]*)"\)/g, 'new Date($1)');

console.log(output);
```

Or assign the result back to `tabData` instead of to a new variable.

Further reading:

- [string `.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Regular expressions at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why you would want to do this, but you can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to do what you asked:

```js
var tabData = '[{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]},{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]}]'

tabData = tabData.replace(/new Date\("([^"]*)"\)/g, 'new Date($1)')

console.log(tabData)
```

Comment: If your question is resolved, an upvote/accept would always be appreciated :)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? (It's the same as my answer, so I'm sure it works...)

Comment: I think someone downvoted all of the posts by lower-reputation users because this was a less-than-adequate question. Some people are of the opinion that we should not help users who fail to meet a certain baseline requirement in their posts.

Comment: I do agree with that opinion *sometimes* - depends on the question (in which case I tend to vote to close the question), but then why only downvote the lower-rep users? If anything the higher rep users should know better... Oh well. I guess I've been around more than long enough to know that many votes are capricious.

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing it like this:

```
var regEx = /new\sDate\("(\d*-\d*-\d*)"\)/g;
var str = ""; //your string as mentioned above
str = str.replace(regEx,"new Date($2)")
```

For eg,

```
var str = 'dsdsadsadsanew Date("12121212")dsdsdsads'
str = str.replace(regEx,"new Date($1)")
//output: "dsdsadsadsanew Date(12121212)dsdsdsads"
```

For global scope in entire string, do as:

**var regEx = /new\sDate("(\d*-\d*-\d*)")/g**

Comment: Got it, changed my regEx

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
var tabData='[{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]},{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new Date("2017-02-25"),"y":20},{"x":new Date("2016-02-25"),"y":15}]}]';


tabData=tabData.replace(/Date\("/g, 'Date(');
tabData.replace(/\"\)/g, ')');
```

**Ouptut:**

> "[{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new
>   Date(2017-02-25),"y":20},{"x":new
>   Date(2016-02-25),"y":15}]},{type:"line",showInLegend:true,dataPoints:[{"x":new
>   Date(2017-02-25),"y":20},{"x":new Date(2016-02-25),"y":15}]}]"